# Texture Glitches When Drawn to Quad

Tags: opengl, glsl, frame-buffer, volumetric-light

Recently been trying to implement volumetric lighting. The alphaness texture comes out perfectly on Renderdoc, however a strange glitch occurs whenever I either try to directly render the texture through a quad to the screen, or through multiplying the alphaness component with my regular texture. A strange static pattern (as shown in the image below) appears on the texture. The texture also periodically turns completely black, and in some frames the image comes out perfectly.

[image: Strange static pattern when drawing texture]

The volumetric lighting texture is rendered to a framebuffer with the settings below:

```
' Configure God Rays Buffer
' -------------------------
godRaysFramebuffer = GL.GenFramebuffer()

' Create color buffers
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, godRaysFramebuffer)
currentFrameTex = GL.GenTexture()
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0)
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, currentFrameTex)
GL.PixelStore(PixelStoreParameter.UnpackAlignment, 1)
GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, All.MirroredRepeat)
GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, All.MirroredRepeat)
GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, All.Nearest)
GL.TexParameterI(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, All.Nearest)
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.R16f, resolutionWidth,
              resolutionHeight, 0, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero)
GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0,
                        TextureTarget.Texture2D, currentFrameTex, 0)

Dim attachments() As Integer = {FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0}
GL.DrawBuffers(attachments.Length, attachments)
```

The alphaness texture, from Renderdoc, is shown below:

[image: Renderdoc alphaness texture]

The fragment shader which samples from the god rays texture (my HDR shader) is shown below. When I comment out the `* texture(godRaysTex, TexCoords).r` it renders perfectly, however without the god rays.

```
#version 440 core

out vec4 out_color;

in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 vPos;

uniform sampler2D hdrBuffer;
uniform sampler2D godRaysTex;

uniform float exposure;

void main() {             
    const float gamma = 1.8;
    vec3 hdrColor = texture(hdrBuffer, TexCoords).rgb * texture(godRaysTex, TexCoords).r;

    // Exposure tone mapping
    vec3 mapped = vec3(1.0) - exp(-hdrColor * exposure);
    // Gamma correction 
    mapped = pow(mapped, vec3(1.0 / gamma));

    out_color = vec4(mapped, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my volumetric lighting shader:

```
#version 440 core

uniform vec2 lightPositionOnScreen;
uniform sampler2D occlusionTex;

const int NUM_SAMPLES = 100;

const float exposure = 0.45;
const float decay = 0.98;
const float density = 0.9;
const float weight = 0.07;

in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 vPos;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {   
    vec2 textureCoords = TexCoords;
    vec2 deltaTexCoords = vec2(textureCoords.xy - lightPositionOnScreen.xy);
    deltaTexCoords *= 1.0 /  float(NUM_SAMPLES) * density;
    float illuminationDecay = 1.0;

    // Evaluate summation from Equation 3 ( see https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch13.html) NUM_SAMPLES iterations.
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; ++i) {
            textureCoords.x = clamp(textureCoords.x, 0.0, 1.0);
            textureCoords.y = clamp(textureCoords.y, 0.0, 1.0);

            textureCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
            vec4 occlusionSample = texture(occlusionTex, textureCoords);
            float alpha = occlusionSample.r;
            occlusionSample.r = 0.0;
            occlusionSample.a = alpha;

            occlusionSample *= illuminationDecay * weight;

            FragColor += occlusionSample;

            illuminationDecay *= decay;
    }

    FragColor *= exposure;
    float alpha = clamp(1.0 - FragColor.a, 0.0, 1.0);
    FragColor.a = 0.0;
    FragColor.r = alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I spotted the issue. I was using the output variable `FragColor` in my god rays shader to perform the calculations. As a result, OpenGL probably would think a fragment was finished being written to on its first assignment, while it was in fact in the process of a calculation in the loop.

Changing `FragColor += occlusionSample;` into `color += occlusionSample;`, where `color` is a `vec4` defined in the scope of the `main()` and then setting `FragColor = color` at the end of the calculations solved the issue.